# Mondrian dont use aggregate tables for average measure

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I found that mondrian dont use aggregate table for average measure if WHERE is exist. How to be with it?

```
SELECT [Measures].[Avg measure] on COLUMNS,
    VisualTotals(Hierarchize({Set of dimension #1})) om ROWS
FROM [Cube name]
WHERE {set of dimension #2}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you may give a try to the sub query:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Avg measure] on COLUMNS,
    VisualTotals(Hierarchize({Set of dimension #1})) om ROWS
FROM [Cube name]
WHERE (select from [Cube name] where {set of dimension #2})
```

Comment: Mondrian don't support sub query(

Comment: You may also try the AVG function with MDX: AVG([Day].[Day].[Day].Members, [Measures].[Sum measure])